# Global variable and if statement comparison to this

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, this, global

I am attempting to run thru some if statements, change a global variable "var1" within the if statement and upon another mouseup event compare the value and proceed based on value of var1.

As I step thru the code and var1 equals $this, the if statement is passed over as if not true. What could be the problem with the comparison as to why it is ignored even when true.

```
var var1 = null;
var var2 = null;


$('.button').on(mouseup, function(evt) {

if (var1 == null) {

    Do Something...
    var1 = $(this);
    return;
}

if (var1 == $(this) {

    Do Something...
    var1 = $(this);
    return;
}


});
```

Comment: Minor correction that might only be a formatting issue: mouseup needs to be in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling $(this) creates a new jQuery object each time. That's why they don't match.

For example:
`$(document) === $(document)   ---> false`

Answer (score 0):

When you call $(this), that will call jQuery to create a new jquery object. Internally, a jQuery object is an array of references to DOM objects. Even though two jQuery objects may contain the same references internally, they are distinct objects, and therefore not ==.

Ex:

```
<button id="theId">test</button>

$("#theId").click(function(){alert($(this) == $(this))}); will always display false;
```

Comment: so I assume its better to compare the actual text of $this, how would I strip the text of $this and save that to the global variable?

Comment: You can do something like this: first you give an id to your <button> then in your script: `var1 = $(this).attr('id');`... `if (var1 == $(this).attr('id')`{...}

Comment: Once a comparison is made, I am using the global variables in this way, if something is true then $(var1).addclass('classname');  So having var1 = $(this) works great when I need to add/remove class to specific elements.  If I use the .attr, how would I use the global variable in the same way.  As of now when I watch the global variable 'var1' its displayed as [div#idname.classname] .

Comment: If you use attr('id') and you set the global variable to the id of the element, then you can call `$("#" + var1).addclass('classname');`